# Accessing jQuery function from inside formview edititemtemplate textbox

Tags: jquery, asp.net, vb.net

I have a webform (code behind VB) with tabcontainer in it, which in turn has a tabpanel in it, which has my formview on it. I have defined a jQuery generic function. I want to access this function from my formview edititemtemplate textbox, on keydown, something like 
$("input[type=text]").keydown(function () {....}

Somehow this function is not getting accessed at all.

Whereas when I access this function from a textbox which is outside tabcontainer, then the function is accessible perfectly.

Can someone pls tell me how to get this function to work from formview edititemtemplate textbox?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a sample of your HTML, this is a standard solution to problems of dynamically added elements. The tabContainer is probably changing the content dynamically.

Attach a single *delegated event handler* to a *non-changing ancestor* of the elements you want to listen to. `document` is the best default if nothing else is closer/convenient.

e.g.

```
$(document).on("keydown", "input[type=text]", function () {....}
```

This works by listening for the event to bubble up the DOM to the connected element. It *then* applies the jQuery selector to just the elements in the bubble chain. It *then* applies your function to only the matching element *that caused the event*.

The end result is that the elements need only match at event time, and not when the event was registered.